# out of memory while rendering and sheep it is not rendering the specific material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, memory-management, pbr, sheepit

my problem is that whenever I try to render a video on my laptop it says out of memory
so I figured out that using a render farm is the choice
it renders on the render farm but the problem is that two of the materials do not render however every other material renders in the frame
for your information I have applied pack all into blend file and also made all the paths relative

I don't know what the problem is can anyone help me

Comment: Are you rendering it directly as a video file or as an image sequence? I would (as almost everybody does) recommend rendering as an image sequence and make it a video afterwards. Then your computer only needs the resources to render one image at a time. And even after crashing you can simply render just the images that are missing instead of having to render the complete video over and over again.

Comment: What happens when the materials go missing? Do they turn dead black, or violet, or something else?

Comment: they are grey. the colour shown in viewport

Comment: the images are also crashing